# How do I modify my array in the callback function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I am pretty new to javascript and trying to figure out how to add values to a caller array in a callback send to another function.

The basic code is:

```
var newArray = new Array();
var oldArray = new Array();
oldArray.push(1);
oldArray.push(2);
oldArray.push(3)

for (var value in oldArray) {
  someclass.functionThatWillPerformAjax(oldArray[value], function() {
     // I am trying to figure out how to pass newArray in this callback
     // so that when we receive the response from AJAX request,
     // the value returned from the response pushed to a newArray
  }
}

// once all calls are done, I have my newArray populated with values returned from server
```

Comment: You need not to pass `newArray` you can access in the callback function through closure.

Comment: that's assuming that my someclass.functionThatWillPerformAjax() exist in another file?

Comment: I think we'd need to see the code for `someclass.functionThatWillPerformAjax` to give you a good indication.

Comment: I'd say make your "callback" function wrapped in an actual ajax success callback function, and pass your new array to the function you're currently calling your callback function.

Comment: "once all calls are done" — That line of code will run when all the Ajax requests are *sent*, **not** when they have *finished*.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```js
var newArray = new Array();
var oldArray = new Array();
oldArray.push(1);
oldArray.push(2);
oldArray.push(3);

var someclass.doAjax = function(element, callback) {
  // perform ajax request
  callback(AjaxRequestResult); // send the result of the ajax request in the callback function
};

oldArray.forEach(function (element) { // for each element in oldArray
  someclass.doAjax(element, function(doAjaxResult) { // perform doAjax function
    newArray.push(doAjaxResult); // push the callback's result into newArray
  });
});
```

But you have to know that, in this case, it's possible that your requests will not be returned in the same order they were called.